# Parsing an output file and creating two lists with python

Tags: python

I have some programming experience, but I'm new to python.  I have an output file that I am looking to parse.  There are two states that a computer could be in:

1. "ERROR: A compatible Trusted Platform Module (TPM) was not detected."
2. "ERROR: The TPM is already on."

I'm looking to write a simple program that takes the output file and creates two lists...one with computers with status #1 and the other with computers with status #2.

The output file looks like this:

```
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Computer Name: AAAAA

ERROR: A compatible Trusted Platform Module (TPM) was not detected.
--- 
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Computer Name: BBBBBB
```

Comment: Do the three hyphens indicate the end of an error message?

Answer (score 1):

How about something that tracks the current computer as a state, and then checks the ERROR message.

Untested code -

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
with open(file_name, 'r') as reader:
    current_computer = None
    for line in reader:
        if line.startswith('Computer Name: '):
            current_computer = line[len('Computer Name: '):]
        if line.startswith('ERROR: A compatible Trusted Platform Module (TPM) was not detected.'):
            list1.append(current_computer)
        elif line.startswith('ERROR: The TPM is already on.'):
            list2.append(current_computer)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

def get_computer(row, reg=re.compile('Computer Name: (\S+)')):
    m = reg.match(row)
    return m and m.group(1)

def line_starts_with(s):
    return lambda line: line.startswith(s)
found     = line_starts_with('ERROR: The TPM is already on.')
not_found = line_starts_with('ERROR: A compatible Trusted Platform Module (TPM) was not detected.')

def process_states(inf, value_fn, state_fns):
    states_matched = defaultdict(list)
    value = None
    for row in inf:
        nv = value_fn(row)
        if nv:
            value = nv
        else:
            for state_label,state_fn in state_fns.items():
                if state_fn(row):
                    states_matched[state_label].append(value)
                    break
    return states_matched

def main():
    with open('input.log') as inf:
        results = process_states(inf, get_computer, {'found':found, 'not_found':not_found})

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

then for testing, I ginned up the following:

```
import StringIO

inf = StringIO.StringIO("""
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Computer Name: AAAAA

ERROR: A compatible Trusted Platform Module (TPM) was not detected.
--- 
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Computer Name: BBBBBB

ERROR: The TPM is already on.
--- 
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Computer Name: CCCCCC

ERROR: The TPM is already on.
--- 
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Computer Name: DDDDDDD

ERROR: A compatible Trusted Platform Module (TPM) was not detected.
""")

results = process_states(inf, get_computer, {'found':found, 'not_found':not_found})
```

which returns

```
{'found': ['BBBBBB', 'CCCCCC'], 'not_found': ['AAAAA', 'DDDDDDD']}
```